# Maximo auto generation of work orders

Tags: auto-generate, maximo

I am new to Maximo and trying to auto generate work orders for each asset for each month starting the first of every month so that I can forward the list to respective asset managers.

I have created job plans and preventive maintenance but I'm unable to proceed from there.

Could someone please provide me some clues or point me the direction where I could do further study?

Answer (score 0):

Two steps from now, you want to turn on an instance of the `PMWoGenCronTask` in the `Cron Task Setup` application. Before you do that, though, you need to go to `Organizations > PM Options` and configure some of the run-time, per-site parameters for that Cron Task.

Once you have the above working, you can investigate @theDcoDer's suggestions for letting people know they have Work Orders (WOs) assigned to them and for helping them manage their work.